# rowReordering is not a function

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with rowReordering. I have a data table :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
  var myDataTable=  $('#employeeTable').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bSortable": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "sAjaxSource": "IndexData",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aoColumns": [
                        { "mData": "employeeNumber" },
                        {
                            "mData": "name",
                            "sWidth": "200px"
                        }
                        ,
                        { "mData": "possition" }

        ],
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
            var id = aData.employeeNumber;
            $(nRow).attr("id", id);
            return nRow;
        },
  });
  myDataTable.rowReordering();
});
```

and as firebug shows it return table with data and rows (tr-s) have id from 1 to x but there is an error "rowReordering is not a function" even if I try `myDataTable.dataTable().rowReordering`

Comment: Did you include the row reordering plugin? I guess not. http://jquery-datatables-row-reordering.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add additional plugin for this.
check the below link for details:

[datatables-row-reordering](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/wiki/Index)

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `rowReordering` plugin, so put this after you've included `datatable` core plugin:

```
<script src="http://jquery-datatables-row-reordering.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.rowReordering.js"></script>
```

Here is the project home page for this plugin:

http://jquery-datatables-row-reordering.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html